# ssh pass multiple values

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, variable

I want to open some ports i do

```
for i in centos7{3..4};do ssh -T $i "for ir in 53 80 443 3000 3306 5910-5930 5432 8140 8443 10090-10100 20 21;do firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=$ir/tcp;done"; done
```

return

```
Error: INVALID_PORT
Error: INVALID_PORT
Error: INVALID_PORT
Error: INVALID_PORT
```

The command is good,because if i do single command on single host return

```
success
success
success
success
success
success
success
success
success
```

The question is,how to pass a multiple variable on ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ir` is being expanded by your local shell and not as you expect on the remote side.
Try escaping the `$`: `… --add-port=\$ir/tcp …`

Or use single quotes instead of double quotes since you don't want anything in the command expanded locally.